# Codeigniter session data lost after redirect (after using memcached as session storage)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached

I had a server with many PHP applications using CodeIgniter as the framework. Everything's running perfectly.

However, after using Memcached as the session storage (I used default file to store sessions before), one of my applications reacted strangely. While others are running well, few of my applications' session missing after redirecting to homepage.

For debugging, I use statement like this

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
           // Your own constructor code

            var_dump($_SESSION); die;

            $this->mysession->check_no_session();
            $this->mysession->check_session_expires();
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->libs->check_main_template('welcome_message','');
    }
}
```

The dump shows me nothing stored in the session: `array(0) { }`

But in my other applications in the same server, when I do debugging, the session data displayed perfectly.

I built these applications using a template, meaning that all configs mostly are the same, so what config/file do I have to see to identify/compare between the OK and error application to spot the config that might cause this anomaly?

Any idea? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: please note that the other applications on the same server (using the same php.ini config) are running well, so I assume that the session config is not the cause of this problem, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think I have found the root cause.

Apparently one of my colleagues set a directive on `index.php` in the application that exceeds memcache's limitation, like this:

```
define('SESSION_TIME_OUT', x);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', SESSION_TIME_OUT);
ini_set('session.cache_expire', SESSION_TIME_OUT);
session_start();
```

Replace `x` with an appropriate number (memcache only accepts numbers under 2,592,000 or 30 days), then the issue no longer exists.