# CodeIgniter 3 session lost on regenerate session id with Memcached driver only

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I am working on a long time running project with CodeIgniter 3 framework. For some months we have been experiencing issues with the session getting randomly lost. I have updated the framework files to the latest version (3.1.13). And it looks like that fixed the problem on the dev servers, however on production it remains. But I noticed it now happens only when the response sends a new session cookie, which happens when the session id is regenerated. When I change the `$config['sess_time_to_update']`, it reflects correctly to the time it takes.

The difference between the dev and prod servers is the session driver - it's files on dev, while on production we use memcached. So I made an experiment and switched the driver to files and the session was lost no more. I also tried a setup with Redis driver and it didn't cause issues too. So it must be something with the Memcached driver. But I don't want to switch to another. There are no errors in the logs. I have also checked the php.ini files and memcached variables are all with their default values.

CodeIgniter v3.1.13, PHP 7.4.3, Amazon ElastiCache for Memcached

Here's the config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'memcached';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 14400;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'host.com:11211';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Any ideas where to look or what to check would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an AWS ElastiCache Memcached cluster, check what endpoint you're using in your config `$config['sess_save_path']`. One option is to use a configuration endpoint (with `.cfg.` in it), the other is an individual node endpoint (with `.0001.`, `.0002.`, etc). If you're using a configuration endpoint, make sure you have Auto Discovery enabled (requires additional installation on your server - [ElastiCache cluster client for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html)). If it's not enabled, your nodes cannot be resolved properly, which causes issues like this.

This turned out to be the case for me. I tried logging messages on session *start*, *regenerate* and *destroy* and with files driver the regeneration was happening, while with memcached it didn't even call any of the functions except `session_start()`. After some investigation I somehow decided to recheck the host and stumbled upon [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Endpoints.html) in AWS. Turned out a second node has been added to our Memcached cluster around the time the problems started, but we have been using the configuration endpoint without having set up this [Auto Discovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/AutoDiscovery.Using.html). I am not sure how the setup had been working at all. So I changed the `$config['sess_save_path']` to the endpoint of one of the nodes instead, and the problems disappeared. Until I install and setup the needed modules and while the nodes are not changed, this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39950648/849365). Apparently, this issue might occur if you set session's maximum expiration time to greater than `memcached`'s limitation for expiry. In that post, OP had solved it by fixing the below configuration variables which you can try:

```php
define('SESSION_TIME_OUT', x);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', SESSION_TIME_OUT);
ini_set('session.cache_expire', SESSION_TIME_OUT);
session_start();
```

Another alternative is to drop `memcached` and use a memory resident `sqlite3` database instead for session storage, I don't think the performance on your production environment will be much different in both cases.